# Error Uploading File Using AJAX SERVLET

Tags: jquery, ajax, servlets, post

I am trying to finish uploading function 
which uses AJAX and SERVLET and external Jquery libary: jQuery Upload File 3.1.10 
I followed the instructions.
Everything is just fine but: I can't get AJAX data from server: 
This is site where I use the instruction: http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php

Also, I use

```
commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar 
commons-io-2.4.jar
```

to handle my file uploading.

My Servlet is fine getting file uploaded, I mean I can get file upload but I couldn't get the params. I just want to catch parameters to add more information to my file in servlet.

This is my AJAX section:

`var objUpload = $("#fileuploader").uploadFile({
    url:"UploadHandling",
    formData: { "category":$('#artCategory').val(), "title": $('#artTitle').val() },
    dynamicFormData: function()
    {
    var data ={ category:$('#artCategory').val(), title: $('#artTitle').val() }
    return data;
    },
    maxFileSize:1024*1000,
    multiple:true,
    autoSubmit:true,
    sizeErrorStr:"File uploaded max size:",
    uploadErrorStr:"Error Uploading File(s)" + category
    });` 

My Servlet code to get params:

```
String category = request.getParameter("category");
String title = request.getParameter("title");
```

This is my HTML Code:

`<div class="input-control text" data-role="input-control">` 
        `<input id="artTitle" type="text" placeholder="Title here">` 
        `<button class="btn-clear" tabindex="-1" type="button"></button>` 
      `</div>` 
     `<label>Category</label>` 
      `<div class="input-control text" data-role="input-control">` 
        `<input id="artCategory" type="text" placeholder="Category here">` 
        `<button class="btn-clear" tabindex="-1" type="button"></button>` 
      `</div>` 
    `<label>` File Upload `</label>` 
    `<div class="input-control text" data-role="input-control">` 
    `<div id="fileuploader">`Select a File`</div>` 
    `</div>`

Thank You

Comment: Some tips: (1) Show the HTML form so we know which parameter is the file. (2) Provide the link to the instructions you followed if you have it. (3) request.getParameter doesn't work with file uploads, use request.getPart.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I just edited my post with more details. I hope you can help me out with this.